# How to use Smart Chinese Analysis for Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed Smart Chinese Analysis for Elasticsearch on our ES cluster, but I do not find documentation on how to specify the correct analyzer.  I would except that I need to set a tokenizer and a filter specifying stopwords and stemmer ...

For example in dutch:

```
"dutch": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
            "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "dutch_stemmer_filter", "dutch_stop_filter"]
          }

with:

"dutch_stemmer_filter": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "name": "dutch"
          },

          "dutch_stop_filter": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords": ["_dutch_"]
          }
```

How to configure my analyzer for Chinese ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this for a certain index (the analyzer is 'smartcn' and the tokenizer is 'smartcn_tokenizer'):

```
PUT /test_chinese
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "type": "smartcn"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET /test_chinese/_analyze?text='叻出色'
```

It should output two tokens (test taken from the [plugin test classes](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-smartcn/blob/master/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/SimpleSmartChineseIntegrationTests.java)):

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "叻",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 2,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "出色",
         "start_offset": 2,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 3
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but what I got from GET /test_chinese/_analyze?text='叻出色' are 3 tokens of 21499, 20986 and 33394, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to install the plugin on all nodes and restart them.